# Due to some base64 character i am not able to upload image in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am uploading a image on a local server but when i am trying to upload on live url that images not convert in proper formate might be.

The php file is same. where i am trying to upload image. I think due to some base64 character not able to uploading image. please suggest me any solutions for base64 character problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also face the same problem. So i replace **@"+"** with **@"%2B"**. May be it is also helpful for you.

```
NSString* result = [base64EncodedImage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePhotoObj.image, 1.0);
NSString *base64Img = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
```